# TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem of pandas especially with moving in dataframe by index numbers.

This is my code:

```
def wolumen(data, swieca):
    list_of_volumen = []
    for k in range(1, 30):
        list_of_volumen.append(data['Volume'][swieca-k])
    print(list_of_volumen)

candle = 0 
hammer = 0

for i in data_frame.index:
    candle+=1
    if data_frame["Close"][i] < data_frame["Open"][i]:
        body = 3 * (data_frame["Open"][i] - data_frame["Close"][i])
        down_shadow = data_frame["Close"][i] - data_frame["Low"][i]
        if body < down_shadow:
            up_shadow = data_frame["High"][i] - data_frame["Open"][i]
            if body > up_shadow:
                hammer+=1
                print("Hammer!!!")
                print(data_frame.loc[i])
                wolumen(data_frame, i)
```

I wanna to analyze some stock data with pandas and yfinance, my data_frame looks like this:

```
                          |  Open    High    Low   Close  Adj Close  Volume
Datetime                  |                                                 
2020-01-10 09:00:00+01:00 |  9.950  10.075  9.900  10.030     10.030  767203
```

I can't add the volumen of row to this lis_of_volumen

The full error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa.py", line 45, in <module>
    wolumen(data_frame, i)
  File "aaa.py", line 28, in wolumen
    list_of_volumen.append(data['Volume'][swieca-k])
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 343, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__sub__
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 320, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__add__
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

Answer (score 0):

Then it is not possible with way you are doing because you are directly doing operation on timestamp  list_of_volumen.append(data['Volume'][swieca-k])

Comment: so i must first add the column of index in this data frame or can do this in other way ?

Comment: Yes definitely you can add any type of index other than datetime or you can convert your timestamp using to_ordinal() but better way is use index as numbers by default and then try to analyze